# Servicestack AutoQuery -> System.TypeLoadException Error

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

I'm trying to servicify an existing RDBMS with C# AutoQuery, but getting this error:

```
  HResult=0x80131522
  Message=Type 'WebApplication1.ServiceModel.CreateCurrency' from assembly 'tmpCrudAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface.
  Source=ServiceStack
  StackTrace:
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.OnStartupException(Exception ex)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.OnStartupException(Exception ex, String target, String method)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.RunPostInitPlugin(Object instance)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.RunAfterPluginsLoaded(String specifiedContentType)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.OnAfterInit()
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Init()
   at ServiceStack.NetCoreAppHostExtensions.UseServiceStack(IApplicationBuilder app, AppHostBase appHost)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Program.cs:line 9
```

The target database is a mySQL database using BINARY(16) as primary key. Could this be the problem? When I target another mySQL database it's working like it should.

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags, so you don't just write one character and press enter to select the first tag. Because then you would select the C language tag instead of C#.

Comment: Show the code of `WebApplication1.ServiceModel.CreateCurrency`.

Comment: I'd say it's likely the binary PK is the problem preventing the Table Data Model from being created which the API is unable to reference.

Comment: @mythz is this something I can fix? This is the documentation I've found
=> Shopware 6 works with UUIDv4 as primary keys instead of auto increments

Comment: @Nesse AutoGen wont be able to infer a Guid from a binary column, but may work if you manually create the `Currency` table (which AutoGen should be able to detect + use) and use `Guid` for the PK then you'll need to create a [custom type converter](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/type-converters) that maps a Guid to a binary column like [OracleGuidConverter.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack.OrmLite/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle/Converters/OracleGuidConverter.cs#L36)

Comment: @mythz It does not seem to work. Could I exclude some tables instead?

Comment: Yes, please see my answer for configuring AutoGen's code-gen behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the tables that [AutoGen](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-autogen) generates the data models and APIs for when configuring the `GenerateCrudServices` instruction, e.g you can exclude a specific table with:

```cs
Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature {
    GenerateCrudServices = new GenerateCrudServices {
        ExcludeTables = { "Currency" },
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx @mythz. When I try to use ExcludeTables It's not recognized within the GenerateCrudServices. => does not contain a definition for 'ExcludeTables'. Should I add an extension?

Comment: @Nesse you'll need to upgrade

Comment: I've got it working using 'ExcludeTables'. Could it be that not every table is generated while excluding tables?

Comment: @Nesse I don't know what this is referring to, if you have a new issue please ask a new question including all relevant context, behavior & error info.